# Did Grails 5.3.0 support Gradle version 6.8.3?

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

Did Grails 5.3.0 support Gradle version 6.8.3 ?

I am running application in JDK 11 with Grails 5.3.0 which is not allowing me to upgrade Gradle version to 7.2 so I went with 6.8.3. I am getting below error. Can I go with Grails 5.3.0 with Gradle 6.8.3 version.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE FAILED in 1m 32s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: If it's saying gradle 8 in "_Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0._" then you're not running gradle 6.8.3